# CSS Background Color

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been looking for over an hour to find where this greenish background color is coming from. I have searched every. single. file. It's driving me crazy.

Does anyone have any suggestions?   Surely it wouldn't be in the .js files, correct?
I can't find the color anywhere in the .html or .css files.

You will see it if you shorten your browser window and refresh... on each side of the video you can see the green bg color.
http://mudchallenger.com/fullpage/examples/videoBackground.html

Suggestions anyone?

Comment: Is there any code? Or can we just start randomly guessing?

Comment: I didn't think to include the entire files in my post since I am unsure as to where it's coming from. I have edited the question to include linked files if that helps.

Comment: For future reference, if you right click on the area and choose "Inspect Element" it will bring up the browser development tools and help you find the cause of the issue. You can open the browser dev tools at any time by pressing the f12 key.

Comment: What changes have you previously made that didn't work?  Where do you think the problem may be coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where your problem is coming from, an inline style on the div with the background color of rgb(27, 188, 155).
[image]

If you are using sublime text or a text editor that lets you scan an entire project try searching for phrases found in the code like "active table" or even the colour itself.

Comment: Searching for the colour is more sensible than searching for the element it is added to since inline styles are likely to be added dynamically.  Also, note that lots of code inspectors output an RGB value for colours entered as hexadecimal so you need to search for both.

Comment: Yeah i made the edit after posting first thinking doh! Wasnt aware that inspectors did that though cool thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The inline style seems set up at:

```
slidesColor: ['#1bbc9b', '#4BBFC3', '#7BAABE']
```

(line 164)

This is then added to the page in line 189 of jquery.fullpage.js

```
if (typeof options.slidesColor[index] !==  'undefined') {
    $(this).css('background-color', options.slidesColor[index]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personal preference is Firefox to do debugging - it is still famous as the lightest resource browser with many addons available and extreme adherence to web standard W3C

Firebug, Webdeveloper Tools, FirePHP and also Colorzilla are necessities for addons - I recommend just using Firefox built in addon search instead of Googling (for security - key word is the mozila domain).

Regarding color, using Colorzilla Eyedrop will allow you to sample any colour on the page.
Then use Webdeveloper to identify (simply by clicking) the part of the page that uses this CSS rule.
There is good documentation and there is no point me reinventing the wheel and directing what you should do.
Use these resources and you will have a vast toolkit for this simple, and many other problems.
Estimated time to install if you don't have them is about 10 minutes, the GUI is fantastic and really there will be very little need to refer to any instructions.

Comment: PS other browsers are available - anyone tried developing with IE ? LOL